# Parsing nested JSON--child properties are null

Tags: c#, json

So I am trying to parse some JSON that is returned to me by a third party api that looks something like:

```
{
    "status":"ok",
    "links":
    [
        {
            "link":
            {
                "link_name":"Sample",
                "link_id":"9999"
            }
        },

    ],//and so on with other nested properties
```

I have created classes to map the JSON to

```
    [DataContract]
    public class JsonTestResults
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string status { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public IEnumerable<Link> links { get; set; }
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class Link
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string link_name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string link_id { get; set; }
    }
```

And I'm pushing the response through this deserializer (taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212344/parse-json-in-c-sharp)

```
public  T Deserialise<T>( string json )
        {
            T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>( );
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream( Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes( json ) ))
            {
                DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer( obj.GetType( ) );
                obj = (T)serializer.ReadObject( ms ); 
                return obj;
            }
        }
```

However, my deserialized results are showing the contents of Link[] as null.  (there is a Link object for each one returned, but the link_name and link_id are null.)

I've checked out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212344/parse-json-in-c-sharp), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802766/c-sharp-parsing-json-formatted-data-into-nested-hashtables), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642590/parsing-json-page), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790754/parsing-json-in-c-sharp) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6220635/c-sharp-json-parsing-parse-escaped-json), but haven't been able to solve this issue.  I am looking for a solution that doesn't require a third party library. (per my lead dev).

I don't believe it's a problem with the classes matching the JSON, but I can post the full code if anyone would like to review it.

Comment: Did you tried to change the Enumerable to a generic list?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the bug is where I'm looking. Look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271356/how-do-i-serialize-this-twitter-entity-response-from-the-stream-api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need one more class to deserialize it correctly

```
public class JsonTestResults
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TempLink> links { get; set; }
}

public class TempLink
{
    public Link link;
}

public class Link
{
    public string link_name { get; set; }
    public string link_id { get; set; }
}
```

I tested it with [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) and worked.

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <JsonTestResults>(json);
```

`JavaScriptSerializer` also works

```
var obj2 = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<JsonTestResults>(json);
```

Comment: lolol offered this solution earlier.  Using this approach, the contents of links is still null, only now it is link = null rather than link_name and link_id = null.

Comment: @Forty-Two As I said I tested it before posting.

Comment: @Forty-Two I'm prety sure it's right too. Maybe there's something wrong with the DataContractJsonSerializer.

Comment: You're right, (both of you).  Apparently it was some problem with my Deserialize method that adding the additional class didn't change anything.  However, as you said, it does indeed work with JavaScriptSerializer()

Comment: Nice @Forty-Two. Fell free to give it for L.B because he sustained his position with more tests than I did. Thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: For VS2017 and beyond, it is possible to generate the classes from the JSON directly although interestingly, the generated code doesn't compile. If I hand code the TempLink structure, it all works.

Answer (score -1):

Its a syntax error in the JSON,

In a JSON Array the last element does not have a ',' after it.

```
 {
"status":"ok",
"links":
[
    {
        "link":
        {
            "link_name":"Sample",
            "link_id":"9999"
        }
    }
],
```

This will work !!

Comment: nah, you are wrong. he leaved the comma to show that there are more elements in the json.